# Can have my own SO/SU/SF style Q/A site?

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

The design of SO/SU/SF is very clean and easy to use, I want to have a similar one to host the Q/A service in my local company, is it open source? or does stack overflow service inc. have the Q/A hosting service?

Comment: If you have SharePoint 2013 running internally there is an OOTB Q&A plugin that can be turned on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that no, you can't self host. And it is not open source.

But there are open source clones exist. One of the example is [cnprog](http://cnprog.com/). You can access the source [here](http://code.google.com/p/cnprog/) and [here](http://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG).

After you have the source, you can do anything you want.

Comment: Man, try translating the badge names with Google... hilarious!

Comment: There is also shapado (http://shapado.com) which is AGPL.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: One caveat: you cannot use Area 51 to create a private site.  Even if you can get enough users, your site will be open for all on the Internet to see.  Also, you will have a `something.stackexchange.com` URL in the beta and a TLD TBD in the potential "real" version, never a `help.yourcompany.com` URL.